# Calculate the energy in a circuit containing a resistor

Tags: integration, derivatives, physics

A voltage peak in a circuit is caused by a current through a resistor. 
[image]

The energy E which is dissipated by the resistor is: 
[image]

 Calculate E if 
[image]

Can anyone please give me some suggestions where to start ? What is the formula to use ?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint :**
Use the Euler formula :
$$
sin(x)=\frac{exp(j\cdot x)-exp(-j\cdot x)}{2j}\\
$$
where $j^2=-1$

**EDIT :**
$$
E = \int_{0}^{\infty} R I_{0}^{2}\cdot e^{-2t/t_{0}}\cdot sin^{2}(2t/t_{0}) \ dt
$$
$$
E = \int_{0}^{\infty} R I_{0}^{2} e^{-2t/t_{0}}\cdot \frac{-2+exp(j4t/t_{0})+exp(-j4t/t_{0})}{-4} \ dt
$$
$$
E = \frac{R I_{0}^{2}t_{0}}{-4}\cdot (-1 + \frac{1}{2-4j} + \frac{1}{2+4j})
$$
$$
E = \frac{R I_{0}^{2}t_{0}}{5}
$$

By the way, downvoting without saying why is childish.

Answer (score 1):

Since $R$ is a constant then the energy is seen to be
\begin{align}
E = R \int_{0}^{\infty} I^{2}(t) \ dt = I_{0}^{2} R \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-2t/t_{0}} \ \sin^{2}(2t/t_{0}) \ dt
\end{align}
By making the substitution $x = 2t/t_{0}$ the integral becomes
\begin{align}
E &=  \frac{I_{0}^{2} t_{0} R}{2} \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-x} \ \sin^{2}(x) \ dx \\
&= \frac{I_{0}^{2} t_{0} R}{4} \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-x} (1 - \cos(2x)) \ dx \\
&= \frac{I_{0}^{2} t_{0} R}{4} \left[ [- e^{-x} ]_{0}^{\infty} - \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-x} \ \cos(2x) \ dx \right] \\
&= \frac{I_{0}^{2} t_{0} R}{4} \left[ 1 - \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-x} \ \cos(2x) \ dx \right] \\
&= \frac{I_{0}^{2} t_{0} R}{4} \left( 1 - \frac{1}{5} \right) \\
E &= \frac{I_{0}^{2} t_{0} R}{5}
\end{align}

Comment: There're two integrations by part missing to conclude that $\int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-x} \ \cos(2x) \ dx$ is equal to $\frac{1}{5}$